# How can i make a input type submit button that will just can used after filling up the form

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, html5-canvas

I made a form on a website but when I click on the submit button without filling the form.I'm going there. I want just when I fill the form completely, then I will go there. with the input, type submit button.
My code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <input placeholder="First Name" type="text"> <br>
        <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text"> <br>
        <input placeholder="Email Adrress" type="text"> <br>
        <input placeholder="Password" type="password"> <br>
        <input placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password"> <br>
        <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="Gender" type="radio">Male <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="Gender" type="radio">Female <br> Birthday
        <select style="cursor: pointer;">
            <option>Select Date</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>21</option>
            <option>22</option>
            <option>23</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option>26</option>
            <option>27</option>
            <option>28</option>
            <option>29</option>
            <option>30</option>
            <option>31</option>
        </select> <br>
    
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/Guest/Desktop/Html/Website/Home.html"><input type="submit"></a>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you will have to check form validation in background for that this will help you (https://www.sitepoint.com/instant-validation/)

then , you have to put your submit button in a div and provide a selector for the div
and in the javascript check if your form is not valid then make that div display as "none" but if you form is valid then make that display as "block"

this code will you:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input placeholder="First Name" type="text"> <br>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text"> <br>
    <input placeholder="Email Adrress" type="text"> <br>
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password"> <br>
    <input placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password"> <br>
    <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="Gender" type="radio">Male <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="Gender" type="radio">Female <br> Birthday
    <select style="cursor: pointer;">
        <option>Select Date</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
    </select> <br>
    <div id="submit">
     <a href="file:///C:/Users/Guest/Desktop/Html/Website/Home.html"><input type="submit"></a>
 </div>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "none";

    //Check formIsValid or not in background
    //if your form is valid then only the submit button will appear
    
    if(formIsValid){
        document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your input elements are not inside the form tag.
For having such form, at least your one or more form element must be required as follows:

```
<form>
     <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" required> <br>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" > <br>
    <input placeholder="Email Adrress" type="text"> <br>
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password" required> <br>
    <input placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password"> <br>
    <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="Gender" type="radio">Male <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="Gender" type="radio">Female <br> Birthday
 </form>
```

as you can see I made the first-name and password required so now if we click on submit button it tells us to fill the required inputs. On the other hand, normally at least one or more forms elements are required usually.
so try to make required at least one or more of your inputs.
hope to help you!
GOOD LUCK!